# How to return with regex php value "+11" from string "+11.00"

Tags: php, regex

I need to return with php value from `strings('-1.00','+2.00','-6.00')` value like `'-1'`, `'+2'`, `'-6'`.
Thank you!

Comment: [Simply add `0` to it](https://eval.in/104550).

Comment: Regex is definitely not the perfect tool for the job, but even then, here you are : `([+\-][\d]+)(?=\.)`. Demo : http://regexr.com?38bo3

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$int = intval($string);
```